# Why was an edit adding an answer to a question approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

The edit [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7825074) is a user with a relatively high reputation (+1500) inserting his own answer *inside* the OP's question.

This edit would be a **very clear** reject to me. Nonetheless, it was approved by three editors with reputations of +3000, +2500, and +7000.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because it was [a comment made by the OP:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858271/more-pythonic-alternative-for-getting-a-value-in-range-not-using-min-and-max#comment47842567_29858271)

> well, i'd say this is pathonic but pathetical :) a = x if 1 < x < 100 else 1 if x < 1 else 100 because it's read as an English sentence. The one in question is not.

Note that the edit comment states

> Adding information from comment into body.

It added a demonstration of "what have you tried" to the question, which some will argue improves it.

Comment: I didn't catch that. Knowing that, I think I too would've approved the edit. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel It said as much in the revision note, which you should be reading when reviewing edits.

Comment: `Comment: Adding information from comment into body`, indeed it does. I believed the editors weren't paying attention, turns out *I* wasn't paying attention.

Comment: To be fair, at very first glance I thought "wtf" as well.